# HighCharts - Add vertical lines from a desire point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Need to draw vertical lines from a desired point rather than starting from 0.

```
plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 1,
            value: 4
        }, {
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 1,
            value: 7
        }],
```

Here is the fiddler link: http://jsfiddle.net/bpswt3tr/4/

My requirement is to draw first vertical line from when y value is 110.2 and 2nd line from when y value is 135.6 instead of starting from zero. i.e above the plot line only. Please suggest how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines) it is unlikely that HighCharts supports this by default, as you are only allowed to associate a value of the current axis with the line.

You might need a preprocessing step that inverts you function to get the appropriate X values. Something like:

```
invert(data, Y) -> list of X values with data[X] = Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the `chart.events.load` call. If you know these are the points you want to add marker elements to then it is fairly straightforward. You first get the current max label value for the yAxis. Then you add a series to the chart with the starting point being your series' value and the second point being the max viewable yAxis value. Then do the same for the second point you want to add a bar to. Then, you need to re-set the yAxis max value to the initial state because highcharts will try to increase the scale to accommodate the new points.

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var yMAx = this.yAxis[0].max;
                console.log(yMAx);

                this.addSeries({
                    data: [{
                        x: 4,
                        y: 110.2,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'triangle'
                        }
                    }, {
                        x: 4,
                        y: yMAx,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'triangle-down'
                        }
                    }, ],
                    showInLegend: false,
                    color: 'red',
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                });

                this.addSeries({
                    data: [{
                        x: 7,
                        y: 135.6,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'triangle'
                        }
                    }, {
                        x: 7,
                        y: yMAx,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'triangle-down'
                        }
                    }, ],
                    showInLegend: false,
                    color: 'red',
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                });

                this.yAxis[0].update({
                    max: yMAx
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bpswt3tr/5/).

Comment: @ wergeld: Thank you. I think adding a new series is very good idea to draw lines something like that. I will try to replicate in my application.